# Getting "HttpHostConnectionException" when application getting redirected to CAS for SAML authentication in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, saml-2.0, cas

I have recorded jmx script for one of my applications where in the authentication is done through CAS SAML. Now when running the script I am getting "Connection Timed Out" exception when the system directs from  my application url to CAS.

For eg: "https://example.com" redirects to "https://cas5.example.com/cas/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO"

On this direction to CAS url, i am getting

Response code  as "Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectionException"
Response message as "Non HTTP  response message: Connect to cas5.example.com:443 failed. Connection timed out:connect"

Solutions tried
Tried to increase the  Timeouts for  the Https Request to 90000 but still facing the same error

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you're not getting the response from your CAS server, the reasons could be in:

1. CAS host/port changed since you recorded the script
2. CAS is down
3. CAS is in Internet and your application is in Intranet and JMeter cannot access Internet because of using corporate [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) or something like this
4. You need a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) connection to access CAS
5. Access to CAS is restricted to JMeter/Java process by your OS [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing))

We can help only in point 3, if this is the case you can make JMeter aware of the upstream proxy settings by:

1. Either providing proxy host,port, credentials, etc. by [command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

   ```
   jmeter -H proxy_host -P proxy_port -t yourtest.jmx
   ```
2. Or setting the proxy host, port, protocols and credentials in [*system.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization), this way you won't need to amend JMeter command line on each execution:

   ```
   http.proxyHost=proxy_host
   http.proxyPort=proxy_port
   etc.
   ```

More information: [Using JMeter behind a proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)